# React Application form cannot POST to my backend api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have already created a backend api with node and express which works great, through Postman and Insomnia, but for some reason my create function wont post to my api. It can login to the API fine, and the form is returned with each user inputted field, but the issue relates to somewhere after axios.post, as if i put in the incorrect url it throws a 404, but if i put in the correct url it doesnt throw any error but completely skips over the .then(response function and goes straight to console.log(3). Any ideas or help relating to this would be great, Thanks!

**Imports**

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {TextField, MenuItem, FormControl, Select, InputLabel, Button, Checkbox} from '@mui/material'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
```

**Submit form code**

```
const submitForm = () => {
        console.log(form)

        let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        console.log(1)

        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/miniatures/create', form,{
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `jwt ${token}`
            }
        })
                .then(response => {
            console.log(2)
            console.log(response.data)
            navigate(`/miniatures/${response.data._id}`)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        console.log(3)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

React likely does not know how to [proxy API requests to the Express server](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

In `package.json` for the front end, try adding:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9000",
```

Then, make your `post` request to  (something like) `axios.post(/miniatures/create)`. The exact path will depend on how you structured your Express routes. It could be something like `/api/miniatures/create`.

> In development, the development server will recognize that it’s not a
> static asset, and will proxy your request.

Comment: Unfortunately it isnt that. If I do it that way it thinks /miniatures is the front end. If i keep it the way it is but give the wrong url it says 404, but it says nothing if I get the url right so im really not sure whats going on.

Comment: Can you post your routes from Express?